# Cannot import Java class with PlayFramework

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm working on a PlayFramework MVC java application, but when I do `import models.Board;` I get a Compilation error saying:

```
error: cannot find symbol
[error] import models.Board;
[error]              ^
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
```

I've gone through all StackOverflow questions related to this error but none of them have fixed my problem. This is the relevant code for my `Application.java` below:

```
package controllers;

import models.Board;

import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    Board board;

    public Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }
}
```

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := """AI-tic-tac-toe"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

crossPaths := false
autoScalaLibrary := false

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs
)
```

This file is located in a controllers folder and Board.java is located in the models folder, both of these folders are in the same app folder. Any help on why this error is occurring would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my target directory:

[image: target directory screenshot]

Comment: Could you show us your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Also, try if the issue still exists after a `sbt clean run`. Intellij gets confused sometimes and SBT is more accurate. If SBT also gives an error, could you post the output?

Comment: Ok so I ran the command and got `[error] {file:/usr/bin/}default-cf1fd7/compile:run: No main class detected.` But I ran the command from my usr/bin because that's where sbt is, do I need to run it in my PlayFramework folder though?

Comment: I don't know much about sbt, but is it the same as activator? If so I use that and I tried a clean run of that and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Should be about the same yeah. Could you upload a screenshot of your entire `target/scala-2.11/classes` directory?

Comment: So for some reason `target/scala-2.11` doesn't exist in my project, but `target/classes` does. In another test project build that I thought was configured the same way though does have the `scala-2.11` folder

Comment: Does your application compile fine under activator?

Comment: Make sure models is inside `app` directory. (app directory should be in your class path, right click and mark directory as sources).

Comment: Ya it complies fine when I'm not importing the `Board`. The `models` directory is inside the `app` directory and `app` is marked as a sources folder

Comment: Clearly your models aren't compiling but I can't figure out why though.

Comment: So the playframework template I used for this project didn't have a `models` folder by default so I made it myself (but it did have `controllers` and `views`). Is there a chance that is why, like some playframework file generated when the project was made has no idea I made a `models` folder basically?

Comment: Add the code for `models.Board` to your question. Also, please, add the complete error message.

Comment: @easiestripes what happens when you delete import statement and trying auto-import with Alt+Enter?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne Alt+Enter doesn't auto-import the `models.Board` when I try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem, of course it was the simplest thing. I'll post what I did just in case anyone runs into a similar issue.

So all it ended up being was I didn't put `package models;` at the top of my `Board.java` file. It is unfortunate that Play doesn't give a better error message for something like that though.